# How to change themes in qupzilla appimage?

Tags: 14.04, themes, browser, qupzilla

I have downloaded the latest version(2.1) of qupzilla as an appimage from [here](https://www.qupzilla.com/startdownload?appimage) and its working fine. I want to change the default theme to [this](https://github.com/QupZilla/qupzilla-plugins/tree/master/themes/cyanotype). I have downloaded the files in a folder called `cyano`. Now how should I add this theme to qupzilla?

First I tried to find **qupzilla** folder inside `/usr/share/` but there is no such folder in my computer

Second I created a **themes** folder inside `/home/me/.config/qupzilla/profiles/default/` and copy paste `cyano` folder to it

But both didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install a new theme in Qupzilla (including for an appimage) you have to put it in `~/.config/qupzilla/themes/`.

It seems the theme you mentioned is not available at the same link anymore and there are not many others available. I have found [this one](https://github.com/francoism90/qupzilla-plasma-theme) and tested for the purpose of this answer, although it is almost identical to the default Linux theme.

[image]

Some notes on Qupzilla an its looks:

- Properly installed (that is: not just as an appimage) it has great integration with the desktop theme. I was able to see that with the Ubuntu repo version 1.8.9 in Plasma 5.
- I am not able to find a way to install later versions, only appimages seem available and they do not have that great theming integration, hence the need for themes. Here they are: https://github.com/QupZilla/qupzilla/wiki/Themes.
- 2.2.5 is the latest version. After that it will [change name to Falkon](http://blog.qupzilla.com/2017/08/qupzilla-is-moving-under-kde-and.html).